# how to reserve an memory block for a program in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, operating-system

I am having two structures and vector of struct objects for both the structures.Now i want to call the first structure 100 times and the second structure 50 times alternatively.But the base address of both vectors should be same. I know it can be done using the union class but I want to try it by implementing the paging concept of OS.
So that I can use the same pages for storing the values of vectors.
This are the following structures:

```
struct a{
    float e;
};

struct b{
    double d;
    float a;
    int c;
};

void main()
{   vector<a> v1;
    vector<b> v2;
    v1.reserve(50000);
    v1.push_back(a());
    cout<<"Base address: "<<&(v1[0])<<endl;
    v1.clear();
    v2.reserve(50000);
    v2.push_back(b());
    cout<<"Base address: "<<&(v2[0])<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to write a custom allocator for your vectors. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

Comment: You want to use the OS directly, but you did not state which OS that is.

Comment: Also, union and OS paging are two very different things. Please explain what it is you are trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: Using paging to solve a problem about union???! Please make sure you really understand what the paging is.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh..I am using windows os..basically what i am trying to do is to hold a memory block and assign that memory to the vector of struct objects.i.e at first it will be assigned to first vector and after clearing hat vector the same memory is allocated to the second vector. So it is a kind of shared memory

Comment: @liliscent, I know paging is a memory management technique ..i just had a thought that it can implemented to solve my purpose..anyways it is not possible as the memory allocation is not contiguous

Comment: @RParthiban Note that if you just `clear` the vector, its internal buffer is not deallocated; the capacity is still the same. You want to additionally call `shrink_to_fit` member function.

Comment: @DanielLangr..okay doing a shrink_to_fit opertion,how is it gonna help me anyway?